# Recover files from hardware failed ssd

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, hardware, flash-memory

I have an ssd that has had a hardware failure of some kind, I can rma it as it is still under warranty but their service does not include data recovery. I have collected my work files from it but my personal files and plugins are still there and I would like to recover them.

The catch...
Bandwidth and total copy size seams to be an issue. Read too much and the drive crashes.
Reports bad sectors everywhere (false) or shuts down the whole os.
So I have since put the drive in an external case so I can hot swap it as I suspect the memory buffer is the issue.
I thought of using rsync with a bandwidth limit as per another question here, but I believe I would need to stagger the copy process to either let the buffer clear itself or cool down.

I am in need of some script or tool to recover my lost data.

Comment: Just use `ddrescue` it can resume and has plenty of other options that might aid you on your quest (including a max rate so you can test that theory)... not much else you can do, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reports bad sectors everywhere (false)

"sectors" is not a thing that exists on SSDs. "blocks" do, and if your drive reports them as bad that means, because there's nothing to fail mechanically:

1. Asserted the address lines to get these bits of the block
2. Read out the memory cells, which means "gotten a vector of voltage readoutss"
3. Tried to convert these to bits, by applying a rather complicated soft-input error correcting code on them
4. Return (success and data) or (error):

   1. Success when trying to decode them (iteratively) yielded an error term ("syndrome" in decoder speak) that was zero at some point
   2. Error when the soft values never actually can be massaged and error corrected to yield a word that has no error

So, you get an error. That means the thing cannot be read out. There's no "the SSD is *wrong* about the data being unrecoverable": It always reads *some* voltages, no matter how broken everything is, and checks whether these pass a check, and corrects them, if necessary, **and** possible.

Therefore:

> Reports bad sectors everywhere

You'll have to trust your SSD on that – it literally cannot read the data. The only thing you can change to "globally" make reading hard although the memory cells (which, by the way, are small capacitors charged to some voltage) are intact is if you "shift" the reference voltage of the ADC that converts the analog voltages to digital values. Then, you get incorrect soft input for your decoder, even if the actual memory was OK.

But that voltage is generated *within the very same die* as the ADC is (so, within your flash memory chip) and should be quite resilient to changes in e.g. supply voltage.

So, maybe it's a thermal thing, really, or some silicon mode failure.

Either way, it would sound to me like you would not want to use rsync, or any file-system level tool, to get data from the drive. That requires the operating system to be able to access the same data spots very frequently, just to understand what data is in which file.

What you'd need to do is make block-device level copy, and to it in small steps. Read (for example) 16 MB into an image file. Wait a while. Read 16 MB… and so on.

This could be done in a ZSH/bash shell script with a loop that reads these blocks sequentially with `dd`, then calls `sleep` to wait, then reads the next and such, or in a few lines of Python. Don't forget to check for errors reading on the way, and abort the procedure when they happen, to restart it at the same point later.

Because an actual prepared solution is asked for:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# Copyright 2022 Marcus Müller
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
# Find the license text under https://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause.html
# THIS SCRIPT IS UNTESTED AND COMES WITH NO WARRANTIES, FOLKS.

IN_DEVICE=/dev/yoursource_ssd
BACKUP_IMG=myimage
LOGFILE=broken_mbs.txt

# get size, round up to full MB
size_in_bytes=$(blockdev "${IN_DEVICE}")
size_in_MB=$(( ( ${size_in_bytes} + 2**20 - 1) / 2**20 ))
#check whether size > 0
if [[ ! ${size_in_MB} -gt 0 ]]; then
  logger -p user.crit "Nope, can't determine size of ${IN_DEVICE}. I'm outta here."
  echo "Failure on input" >&2
  exit -1
else
  logger -p user.info "Trying to back up ${IN_DEVICE}, size ${size_in_MB} MB"
fi

if fallocate -l "${size_in_MB}MiB" "${BACKUP_IMG}" ; then
  logger -p user.info "preallocated ${BACKUP_IMG}"
else
  logger -p user.crit "failed to preallocate ${BACKUP_IMG}"
  echo "failure on output" >&2
  exit -2
fi

failcounter=0
MB=$((2**20))
for i in {0..$((${size_in_MB}-1))}; do
  if \
    dd \
      "if=${IN_DEVICE}" \
      "of=${BACKUP_IMG}" \
      "ibs=${MB}" "obs=${MB}" \
      "skip=${i}" "seek=${i}" ; \
  then
    echo "backed up MB nr. ${i}"
  else
    failcounter=$(( ${failcounter} + 1 ))
    echo "${failcounter}. error: couldn't backup MB nr. $i" > &2
    echo "${i}" >> ${LOGFILE}
    logger -p user.err "couldn't backup MB nr. $i"
  fi
  sleep 0.5
done
echo "Got ${failcounter} failures"
exit ${failcounter}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I did not have my computer with me as I had to type it from memory. I can explore the hdd on Linux as the original was Windows. But any major operations does kill the device, even tried a live clonezilla with a rescue flag didn't help, it actually broke clonezilla.

Comment: That being said, I am not a python coder and do not know where to get started on this type of operation. I have bought a backup ssd to copy the files onto but for coding, I'm more of a Windows/c#/js programmer so this level of operation and technical side I only know in theory

Comment: I can't accept this answer as it doesn't resolve my issue for data recovery, only offering insight as to the cause of the hardware fault.

Comment: hey, I kind of tried to address that in the last three paragraphs of my answer.

Comment: I understand what the concept is, I know what python is but not every linux users knows how to program in Python or knows how to do this kind of thing. A solution is needed, not simply just re-iterating my initial assumption of staggered copying. as mentioned, I did attempt with clonezilla for a block copy with rescue as an indication of what solutions I am able to do.

Comment: ah! I understand :) well, start zsh, do something like `for i in {0..$((${size_in_MB}-1))}; do dd if=/dev/yoursource of=backup-${(l:6::0:)i} ibs=1M skip=$i || logger -p user.err "couldn't backup MB nr. $i"; sleep 0.5; done` or so

Comment: @DIGIByte I've not had a chance to check it, but, it's a free development effort, so here you go in the answer :)